# Multiple CXF bundles in OSGI binding to same address

Tags: spring, osgi, cxf, apache-karaf, karaf

I have multiple WARs that expose CXF JAXRS endpoints. They have similar web.xml

```
<web-app id="app1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

They share common Spring configuration (named `common-rest.xml`)

```
<beans>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <context:annotation-config />  

    <bean id="httpDestinationRegistry"
    class="org.apache.cxf.transport.http.DestinationRegistryImpl" />

    <bean id="baseJaxRSServer"
        abstract="true"
        lazy-init="false"
        class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.JAXRSServerFactoryBeanDefinitionParser.SpringJAXRSServerFactoryBean"
        init-method="create"
        p:address="${http.server}/" />
</beans>
```

And every bean has similar configuration

```
<beans>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/app/common-rest.xml" />

    <bean id="app1JaxRSServer"
        parent="baseJaxRSServer"
        p:serviceBeans-ref="app1ServiceBeans" />
</beans>
```

Exact path is defined in each bundle's MANIFEST

```
Web-ContextPath: app1
```

The problem is I can't make multiple bundles work together. With single bundle it's working OK, but if I try to run another one I get exception for creating `app1JaxRSServer` bean

```
org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: There is an endpoint already running on /.
```

Using Karaf 4.0.9, CXF 3.1.13, Spring 3.2.18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, there was a problem with DestionationRegistry which was created by default by CXF HTTP Transport OSGI Bundle (the one that registered default /cxf/* endpoint). I had to disable this bundle by setting

> org.apache.cxf.osgi.http.transport.disable = true

in Karaf properties

Answer (score 0):

The reason is

```
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

If you have multiple bundles with this settings their endpoints will clash.

Try to use different prefixes per bundle.

Comment: It dosen't help. The configuration I posted was working OK with Karaf 3 and CXF 2.6. Now I upgraded the versions and faced this error

Comment: Actually you are right the Web-Contextpath should already provide a prefix. Lets see if someone has a better idea.. If not you should open an issue at CXF.